# rake file with a create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have rake file when i create record with it returns nil for fields that are references

```
namespace :winner do
  desc "Generate sitemap"
  task :create_winner => :environment do
binding.pry
      date = DateTime.now.utc
      likes = Like.where('created_at >= ? and created_at <= ?', 2.week.ago.beginning_of_week, 1.week.ago.end_of_week).select(:selfy_id)
      top = Selfy.where(id: likes)
      @user = top.order("COALESCE(likes_count, 0) DESC").limit(1).pluck(:user_id)
      @selfy = top.order("COALESCE(likes_count, 0) DESC").limit(1).pluck(:id)
    Winner.create(
    date: Time.now,
    user_id: @user,
    selfy_id: @selfy
    )
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

you should either create with the `id` or with the `association`

```
Winner.create(date: Time.now, user: @user, selfy: @selfy)
```

or

```
Winner.create(date: Time.now, user_id: @user.id, selfy_id: @selfy.id)
```